# Is TC++PL 4th Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup outdated?

Tags: c++, c++11, books

*First of all, I hope this question doesn't fall under "Asking For Books Recommendation" Category.*

Since TC++PL covers C++11, it is 3 revisions old (C++14, C++17, C++20), the ISO group is working on C++23, and I think a 5th revision won't be published anytime soon. So is it outdated?

Comment: If C++ standards were version numbers, I think C++11 would be called 2.0, while C++14 and 17 would be 2.1 and 2.2, respectively. Anyway, if you want Stroustrup's newer book, which is also a bit more lightweight, try [A Tour of C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/tour2.html) which covers C++17 and some C++20 features.

Comment: This is a pretty fair question (with a pretty good answer), I can't understand why it's so down voted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any programming book is practically guaranteed to be outdated as soon as it hits the shelves. The Stroustrup book is no exception.

But that does not mean such books would be useless. C++11 introduced fundamental language concepts such as move constructors and lambdas that render pre-C++11 material largely obsolete. For all later C++ versions, it is still important to understand the language in its C++11 feature set. The Stroustrup book does a good job of explaining the language in its massive breadth. This holistic understanding does not hinge on various trivia that was changed in later versions.

Of course, later versions did change the language. C++14 is mostly just a continuation and completion of the changes started in C++11. C++17 contains various fundamental improvements and lots of new libraries, but it doesn't invalidate C++11 knowledge. C++20 is a radical change of the language with concepts, modules, and coroutines. The catch is that as of 2021, no compiler supports this language in all its glory (though both MSVC and GCC support large subsets).

So do buy a C++11 book if you would have otherwise bought it. If you want to start programming now, it makes no sense to wait for C++20 material and tooling to arrive. You won't have to unlearn a lot when moving from C++11 to C++17. Of course, some people don't benefit from reading 1300-page books at all. In any case, the book should be paired with more up to date reference material such as the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) website, the [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/), and the [Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). Before they become part of the standard library, many innovations are implemented in the [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) or in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), which also means that your exact C++ version is less relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It covers C++ 11. That means it's still relevant and always will remain relevant to C++ 11.

If you're using a different version of the language, use a different edition or a different book that's relevant to that version.

Of course most of what's relevant to C++ 11 will still be relevant in later versions as they're incremental changes rather than a complete redesign (as was the case with C++ 3 as compared to C++ 2) so while it won't cover everything it's still a useful book to have if you can't get a newer edition.

It's the same with other languages and tools. Java 16 may be the latest and (depending on who you ask) greatest, but many (if not most) people still use Java 8 or 11 because those are TLS versions. Java 8 centric books aren't outdated because there's a new version of the language out there, they're at worst incomplete in that they don't cover all the new stuff added since, which in most cases would be covered by some addendum rather than an entirely new book if you want to have that information (the addendum being release notes, blogposts, etc. in today's world more than anything).

Back to C++, I still have numerous books about C++ 3, which was the current version when I was learning the language and I've not used C++ much since. Those books are still (mostly) relevant on their topical information, they just use a syntax that may not be what current language versions would prefer in all places.